# Finding time it takes to sort an array using selection sort (C++)?

Tags: c++, sorting, time, selection, ctime

The assignment I have asks me to write a class that displays the time it takes (in milliseconds) to sort an array that holds 100,000 randomly generated items using a selection sort.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

class StopWatch{
 private:
    int startTime;
    int finishTime;

 public:
     StopWatch(){
     startTime = 0;
     finishTime = 0;

    }
    StopWatch(double t){
     startTime = t;
    }

    int start(){
     return startTime;
    }


    int sort(){
        int data [100000];
        for(int x= 0; x < 100000; x++){
        data [x] = rand()%98+1;
        }
    int tmp;


    for (int i = 0; i < 100000 -1; i++){

        for (int j = i+1; j < 100000; j++){

            if (data[i] > data[j])
            {
                tmp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = tmp;
            }
        }   
    }       
    finishTime = time(0);
    return (finishTime-startTime);          
    }




};


int main()
{
StopWatch s(time(0));
cout << "The amount of time it took to sort is " << s.sort()<< " seconds" << endl;
}
```

My idea was to get the time before I sorted it, then after the for loop of the sort broke out, to take the time again, then subtract this new time by the old time. With my existing code, I get 0. One other question I had is my teacher instructed us to only use ctime and time(0) in the program, but looking into it, it seems that there are many other useful functions to write this program with. Can anyone give insight to the best way possible to do this, or as to why my teacher would have us only use this one function in ctime?

Comment: As a programming teacher I surmise that your teacher limited you to ctime and time because they will work, are documented, are widely used, and are reasonably easy to figure out. That would be my motivation.

Comment: @nicomp Ah alright that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Well there are plenty of things to point out about this code. But first of all try to make the variable types match. startTime and finishtime are both integer members, but you initialize them with a double. You are probably loosing data in the conversion. (using `time_t` would be even better)